# error '800a005e' Invalid use of Null: 'CDate' when using a function in ASP Classic-VBScript

Tags: function, asp-classic, error-handling, vbscript

I've made a function called FormatDT, and I put it on `\include\basic_function.asp`

here is the code of that function:

```
function FormatDT(ddate,format)
        ddate = cdate(ddate)
        Set re = New RegExp
        re.Pattern = "%."
        re.Global = True
        re.IgnoreCase = False
        're.MultiLine = True
        set matches = re.execute(format)
        hasil = ""
        tmp = format
        for each match in matches
            fmt = match.value
            select case fmt
                case "%d" hasil = day(ddate)
                case "%D" hasil = right("00" & day(ddate),2)
                case "%m" hasil = month(ddate)
                case "%M" hasil = right("00" & month(ddate),2)
                case "%b" hasil = left(MonthName(month(ddate)),3)
                case "%B" hasil = MonthName(month(ddate))
                case "%y" hasil = right(year(ddate),2)
                case "%Y" hasil = year(ddate)
                case "%h" hasil = hour(ddate)
                case "%H" hasil = right("00" & hour(ddate),2)
                case "%n" hasil = minute(ddate)
                case "%N" hasil = right("00" & minute(ddate),2)
                case "%s" hasil = second(ddate)
                case "%S" hasil = right("00" & second(ddate),2)
                case else hasil = replace(fmt,"%","")
            end select
            tmp = replace(tmp,fmt,hasil)
        next
        FormatDT = tmp
    end function
```

I use this function in here:

```
<input style="text-align:center" class="label" style="width:6em;" type="text" id="txtDate" name="txtDate" size="12" value="<%=FormatDt(dtglvalid,"%M/%D/%Y")%>" >
```

and when I load the page, I got error message like this:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a005e'   Invalid use of Null: 'cDate'
>   /include/basic_function.asp, line 234

line 234 located on `ddate = cdate(ddate)`

how to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP is complaining about the variable `ddate` being `NULL`. Looking at you code, it looks like the variable `dtglvalid` is NULL which is passed to the function and causes the error. You could do something like:

```
<input ... value="<% if not IsNull(dtglvalid) then Response.Write FormatDt(dtglvalid,"%M/%D/%Y") %>">
```